# Setting a picture from my Resources programmatically to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

How can I set a picture to a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) in code?

The code below gives me the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert Bitmap to
>   String.

```
    private void ptbLocalidadAdd_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ptbLocalidadAdd.ImageLocation = Properties.Resources.addg;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the resource is a bitmap, this should work:

```
ptbLocalidadAdd.Image = Properties.Resources.addg;
```

Comment: What if the bitmap is created during the life of the application? How do we save it as a resource?

Comment: @Garreh: if you have the memorystream of the bitmap in memory then convert it to a bitmap object and assign that as the `Image` instead of the `Properties.Resources.addg`. I think saving the dynamically created image to the resources seems like a bit of overkill unless you will use it when the program runs for a second time or any subsequent times.