# Programmatically change jpg in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have a simple application in winforms where I need to change the image depending on an if statement.  The statement is triggering because other things are also happening.  I've looked at the following examples:

[Dynamically set Image of a Picturebox in winforms applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440986/dynamically-set-image-of-a-picturebox-in-winforms-applications)

[Change PictureBox's image to image from my resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560105/change-pictureboxs-image-to-image-from-my-resources)

[Setting a picture from my Resources programmatically to a PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845500/setting-a-picture-from-my-resources-programmatically-to-a-picturebox)

and none of these have led me to a solution to why I'm unable to change the image.

Here's what I have tried:

```
pictureBox1.Image = global::KatReminder.Properties.Resources.angry_orange_cat;

pictureBox1.Refresh();

pictureBox1.Load();

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"\Resources\angry-orange-cat.jpg");

pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = KatReminder.Properties.Resources.angry_orange_cat;

pictureBox1.Refresh();

pictureBox1.Load(@"\Resources\angry-orange-cat.jpg");
```

In the two examples with files, the full path I'm using has been truncated for this example.

Comment: You should try calling `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`. Just guessing, because I really have no idea why what you have already wouldn't work.

Comment: Several of your methods should work. I wonder why you didn't also try `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = yourPath;` But if none work the problem is elsewhere. Please show us the calls in their context and also make sure they are actually reached by putting a breakpoint on them! You may want to give your Picturebox a Border to make sure you can even __see__ it i.e. it is not hidden, displaced or size zero

Comment: @Jashaszun, please make your .Invalidate an answer.  This is what worked for me and I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @Nallware Happy to oblige! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try calling `pictureBox1.Invalidate()`. Usually that works for me when I need to make sure something gets repainted.